# Diameter of pseudoholomorphic curves

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

Fix an almost-complex structure $J$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}.$ Let $u: (D^2, i) \to (\mathbb{R}^{2n}, J)$ be a $J$-holomorphic disk.

My question: can one prove an a-priori bound on the diameter of $u$ (say in terms of the norm of $J$)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the diameter'?  Are you fixing a metric on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$?  If so, is it assumed compatible with $J$ somehow?    In general, I expect the answer is 'no' since, for the standard complex structure and metric on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ there is no bound on the diameter of holomorphic discs.

Comment: @RobertBryant For the setting I had in mind, the curve had boundary in a Lagrangian submanifold. I was hoping to control the "size" of the curve" (with respect to some, say J-compatible, background metric). However, the question as posed is clearly too general, as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You can Riemann mapping theorem to create a holomorphic disk of any diameter in case $n=2$.